# If element not present within a tag then print "" - python programming

Tags: python

```
s = '''
:20:name
:21A:Address
:22B:phone
:57A:/256789422254
TEST VALUE
:59B:/REST_MA
LINE1
:59C:TEST
'''
```

code written:

```
    if ':57A:' in s:
        a, b = s[s.index(':57A:') - 1 :].strip().split("\n")[:2]
        a = a.split(':')[2]
        print("value of A:" + a[1:7])
        print("value of B:" + b)
    else:
        print('not found')
```

result displayed:

value of A:256789
value of B:TEST VALUE

If :57A: does not have two lines 
Ex:

```
s = '''
:20:name
:21A:Address
:22B:phone
:57A:/256789422254
:59B:/REST_MA
LINE1
:59C:TEST
'''
```

Then I want output as 
Expected:
value of A: 256789
value of B: ''

Actual:
value of A:256789
value of B::59B:/REST_MA

because value of A and B should come from :57A:
but from output it tooks :59B:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check for your tag starting with `:` in b

```
if ':57A:' in s:
    a, b = s[s.index(':57A:') - 1 :].strip().split("\n")[:2]
    a = a.split(':')[2]
    print("value of A:" + a[1:7])
    if b.startswith(':'):  # add this check
        b = '' 
    print("value of B:" + b)
else:
    print('not found')
```

Answer (score 0):

Check whether the variable "b" starts with a colon to verify if it's a new field or a continuation of your 57A field.

```
if ':57A:' in s:
    a, b = s[s.index(':57A:') - 1 :].strip().split("\n")[:2]
    a = a.split(':')[2]
    print("value of A:" + a[1:7])
    if b.startswith(":"):
        print("value of B: ''")
    else:
        print("value of B:" + b)
else:
    print('not found')
```